# ACF: search by relationship field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have used ACF relationship fields. the field name is `international_mins_category_a_countries` . The field is having multiple values.

If I print it(`(get_field("international_mins_category_a_countries", get_the_ID())`) prints an array -

```
array
(
    [0] => 737
    [1] => 734
    [2] => 723
    [3] => 1484
}
```

now I am trying to search/filter the posts with a value say `737`.

But I am not getting any result.

```
Code I have used to filter that is ---

'meta_query'    =>  array(
            array(
                'key'       =>  'international_mins_category_a_countries',
                'value'     =>  '737',
                'compare'   =>  'IN',
            ),
        )
```

But no result. Can anyone help ?

Comment: So you're returning ONLY the ID in your relationsship - But you can actually set it to return the entire post object - that way you already have all of the data.

Comment: Yes I have all the data, but I don't want to select all the data, insetad I would like to select those have that ID

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? What kind of relation field it is for example? Also can you provide the whole WP Query arguments.

Comment: @justkidding96, those are ids of another post types, say country.

Comment: @Alice So you want to retrieve all posts by id from that relation field array?

Comment: yes.... you got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data from the ACF relationship field is stored in the database as a serialized array which isn't an ideal format for this type of query. The array has been condensed down into a single string in the database rather than stored as multiple records.

That means you have to use a LIKE clause to find the matching records.

You need to set the compare argument to LIKE with quotes around the ID to prevent non-exact matches (e.g. 7374, 5737, etc).

```
'meta_query'    =>  array(
    array(
        'key'     =>  'international_mins_category_a_countries',
        'value'   =>  '"737"',
        'compare' =>  'LIKE',
    ),
)
```

ACF isn't going to give you much control over how this data is stored but I would point out that LIKE queries often perform poorly.

Documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Comment: so if the id is 7, then it will match 737 too

Comment: No, that's the purpose of the double quotes wrapped around the ID. They're going to prevent that type of false match.